# Saving offline copy of Google Python tutorial using python.

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write python code to save offline copy of "Google python tutorial" so that I can access the file even when I am not connected to internet. 
For this I am importing the following libraries - urllib, re, BeautifulSoup, OS
The idea is to identify all urls under the navigation path (class - gc-toc) and then loop through each url and save the html file locally. Below is the code for the same.

My questions are,

1. The downloaded html files tries to access the css and js files from
   online. How can I download these files through the program?
2. The whole program seem cumbersome at the moment. Can you suggest
   ways to improve it? For ex, I like to avoid using Re and use BeautifulSoup to extract the links under 'gc-toc' class.

   ```
   import urllib
   import re
   from BeautifulSoup import *
   import os

   #The URL from which the tags are to be scraped from
   url = 'https://developers.google.com/edu/python/'
   html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

   #The scraped tags contain relative path. Need to append with the baseurl for downloading
   base_url = 'https://developers.google.com'
   #save path
   save_path = 'D:\My Local Directory'
   urllist = list()

   # Retreive all anchor tags
   tags = soup.findAll('nav',{'class':'gc-toc'})

   for tag in re.findall('a href="(.+?)" title="',str(tags)):
       urllist.append(tag)

   print 'The number of links extracted is', len(urllist)
   print '----------Printing Urls---------------'
   for url in urllist:
       full_url = urllib.basejoin(base_url, url)

       if url.find('youtube') > 0: continue

       #Open the webpage and read html
       print 'Opening webpage file: ', full_url
       response = urllib.urlopen(full_url)
       response_html = response.read()

       #save the html file offlne
       print 'saving html file as ', url.split('/')[-1] +'.htm'

       output_file = open(os.path.join(save_path, url.split('/')[-1] +'.htm'),'w')
       output_file.write(response_html)
       output_file.close()
   ```

Comment: `wget --no-parent --mirror -p --html-extension --convert-links -e robots=off -P . https://developers.google.com/edu/python/`   I know this is not helping you out with your python code, but this works. doing it in python is actually not a trivial job, as you have to fetch all urls -  images and javascript inclusive - and you have to rewrite the html to point to the downloaded files.

Comment: Thanks. How do you do this for windows?

Comment: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: @jgritty seems like your man on that one ;) good luck

Answer (score 1):

you might not actually want to use python. If all you want is the html from the page you could just use wget. `wget http://my.url` will get the html of a page if that's all you want. alternately, using the excellent `requests` api, you could do something similar to this.

```
import requests
open('page', 'w').write(requests.get(url).text)
```